# Is there any way to get access to a item in a list in another list in one line of code?

Tags: python

Im trying to access to a item in the list with one line of code, but all I can do is this...
Here is my code

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please do not post source code as images.  Copy and paste the text itself into your question.  Do that right now...as soon as you read this.  Hit the "Edit" button and make the changes

Comment: Are you trying to access the element containing the string `"6"`?

Comment: `print(lst[1][2])` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just use square brackets. So for a list `foo`, `foo[x]` returns the element at index `x`. This can be chained for nested lists.

```py
foo = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(foo)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(foo[1])
# [4, 5, 6]

print(foo[1][2])
# 6
```

Comment: When I tried with turple instead of list inside another list, it says "'tuple' object is not callable". is there any ways to do it for turple?

Comment: @LinFang That means you were probably using parentheses instead of square brackets. `x(...)` requires `x` be callable, but `x[...]` requires `x` be indexable. Arrays and tuples are indexable since you can take an index into to them, but can not be called like functions.